# Calculating total of rows

Tags: php, mysql

I fetching and displaying records from database like this

```
SELECT purchorders.orderno,
                    suppliers.suppname,
                    purchorders.orddate,
                    purchorders.deliverydate,
                    purchorders.initiator,
                    purchorders.requisitionno,
                    purchorders.allowprint,
                    purchorders.status,
                    suppliers.currcode,
                    currencies.decimalplaces AS currdecimalplaces,
                    SUM(purchorderdetails.unitprice*purchorderdetails.quantityord) AS ordervalue
                FROM purchorders 
                INNER JOIN purchorderdetails 
                ON purchorders.orderno = purchorderdetails.orderno
                INNER JOIN suppliers
                ON purchorders.supplierno = suppliers.supplierid
                INNER JOIN currencies 
                ON suppliers.currcode=currencies.currabrev
                WHERE purchorders.orderno=purchorderdetails.orderno
                GROUP BY purchorders.orderno,
                    suppliers.suppname,
                    purchorders.orddate,
                    purchorders.initiator,
                    purchorders.requisitionno,
                    purchorders.allowprint,
                    purchorders.status,
                    suppliers.currcode,
                    currencies.decimalplaces LIMIT 5
```

I am getting the result properly. But i want to calculate and display the result of ordervalues which i have displayed (total of all 5 as i limit it to 5)

I tried doing like this

```
$SalesOrdersResult2 = DB_query($SQL,$db);
while ($row = DB_fetch_array($SalesOrdersResult2))
{
$FormatedOrderValue2 = locale_number_format($row['ordervalue'],$row['currdecimalplaces']);
$Total = $array_sum($row['ordervalue']);
$FormatedOrderDate1 = ConvertSQLDate($row['orddate']);
                        $FormatedDelDate1 = ConvertSQLDate($row['deliverydate']);

                        echo " <tr><td> " . $row['suppname'] . " </td>";
                        echo " <td>$FormatedOrderDate1</td><td>$FormatedDelDate1</td><td> " . $row['initiator'] . " </td><td>$FormatedOrderValue2</td><td> " . $row['status'] . " </td></tr> ";

                    }
        echo "<tr><td colspan='3'>Total---</td><td colspan='2'>$Total</td></tr></tbody>";
```

But it says **"Fatal error: Function name must be a string in  ..."**

Somebody please help me in doing this
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're trying to do something like this?:

```
$SalesOrdersResult2 = DB_query($SQL, $db);
$Total = 0;
while ($row = DB_fetch_array($SalesOrdersResult2))
{
    $FormatedOrderValue2 = locale_number_format($row['ordervalue'],$row['currdecimalplaces']);
    $Total += $row['ordervalue'];
    $FormatedOrderDate1 = ConvertSQLDate($row['orddate']);
    $FormatedDelDate1 = ConvertSQLDate($row['deliverydate']);
    echo " <tr><td> " . $row['suppname'] . " </td>";
    echo " <td>$FormatedOrderDate1</td><td>$FormatedDelDate1</td><td> " . $row['initiator'] . " </td><td>$FormatedOrderValue2</td><td> " . $row['status'] . " </td></tr> ";
}
echo "<tr><td colspan='3'>Total---</td><td colspan='2'>$Total</td></tr></tbody>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `$` before `array_sum`.

Comment: if i remove it gives error
Warning: array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in

Comment: That's because `array_sum` is not what you need. You need `+=`.

Comment: yeah. i never realized it :(